# Flash cc As3 instance checking for direction

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My main question here if there is a way that as3 can check for which side or direction of an instance is true? For example, lets say there's a block. I want flash to be able to detect which direction of the block the player is on. Like check if the player is standing in the direction the right side of the block is facing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to be able to tell if something is on the left or the right side?

```
if (block.x < player.x) {
    // block on the left
} else {
    // block on the right
}
```

Comment: Not just side but facing cuz the collision code for my paltformer has been a bit tricky. When my player is looking on its right side, basically its checking if its greater than the block's left side. Now lets say im on the right side of the block. Its still greater than the block's left side. Thus the player goes back to its left side which is something i havent been able to work around. Im looking for distinguishing conditions and rules that can only apply to left and right collision. So thats why i thought of seeing if as3 can check the specific direction of the block based on its side.